# clickable bar chart lebels using google chart api

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, google-visualization

I am using google chart api to create my bar charts on my dashboard. When i create bar chart using api it will create beautiful bar chart for me but as per my requirement i need a hyperlink on bar label values mentioned in picture.

[image: Image shows bar chart i have and circle shows labels where i need to place a hyperlink]

```
    function drawStackedChart(reqCategoryId,fcategoryName)
        {

        $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/TheSanshaWorld/sfcms/fetch-complaint-result-for-other-category?categoryId="+reqCategoryId,
        datatype: "json",
        success : function(jsonData)
        {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         // Add columns
        data.addColumn('string','categoryName');
        data.addColumn({type: 'number',role: 'interval'});
        var complaintStatus = jsonData[0].complaintStatus;

        for(var i=0;i<complaintStatus.length;i++)
        {
        data.addColumn('number',complaintStatus[i].statusName);
        data.addColumn({type: 'number',role: 'scope'});
        }
        data.addRows(jsonData.length);
        var maxVal=jsonData[0].totalCountComplaint;
        for(i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++)
        {  
// trying to create hyperlink
        data.setCell(i,0,'<a href="next.html">+jsonData[i].categoryName+</a>');
        data.setCell(i,1,jsonData[i].categoryId);
        for(j=0; j< jsonData[i].complaintStatus.length; j++)
        {
        data.setCell(i,parseInt(jsonData[i].complaintStatus[j].statusId)*2, jsonData[i].complaintStatus[j].countComplaint);
        data.setCell(i,parseInt(jsonData[i].complaintStatus[j].statusId)*2+1, jsonData[i].complaintStatus[j].statusId);
        }

        if(jsonData[i].totalCountComplaint>maxVal)
        maxVal=jsonData[i].totalCountComplaint;
        }
        var options = {
        title : fcategoryName+' Complaints Dashboard',
        titleTextStyle : {
        fontName : 'Arial',
        fontSize : 18,
        bold : true,
        },
        isStacked:true,
        chartArea: {width:'50%',height:'75%'},
        bar: {groupWidth: '50%'},
        tooltip : {
        isHtml : true,
        textStyle : {
        fontName : 'sans-serif',
        fontSize : 14,
        bold : false
        }
        },
        hAxis:{
        title:'status values',
        gridlines : {
        count : maxVal+1
           },
        baseline:maxVal,//static
        },
        vAxis:{
        title:'Complaint\'s categories',
        textStyle : {
        fontName : 'sans-serif',
        fontSize : 18,
        bold : false,
        },
        },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        new google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectionHandler);
        function selectionHandler() {
        // code for selection handler
    }
```

Comment: looks like you're missing single quotes, should be --> `'<a href="next.html">' + jsonData[i].categoryName + '</a>'` -- but I doubt that will help, the chart will show the HTML, not the "hyperlink". I would suggest using the chart's `select` event instead. The user would need to click on the chart bars, not the label. Then you can call `getSelection` to see what the user clicked and send them to the desired page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution of this problem by adding click event and got a target id. 
and target id contains all the information regarding the click event so using this target id we can easily find out the click information.
Code:

```
var handler = function(e) {
console.log(e);
var parts = e.targetID.split('#');
console.log(parts);
if(parts[0]=="vAxis")
{
if (parts.indexOf('label') >= 0) {
var idx = parts[parts.indexOf('label') + 1];
$(document).ready(function() {$('#prev').show();});
categoryName=data.getValue(parseInt(idx),0);
c=categoryId=data.getValue(parseInt(idx),1);

}
}
else if(parts[0]=="legendentry")
{
//alert(parts[1]);
var op=parseInt(parts[1]);
optionBase(op);
chart.setSelection([]);
}
else if(parts[0]=="bar")
{
categoryName=data.getValue(parseInt(parts[2]),0);
categoryId=data.getValue(parseInt(parts[2]),1);
statusId=data.getValue(parseInt(parts[2]),2);

chart.setSelection([]);
}
};
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', handler);
```